# How to access files from a hidden folder in react-native-fs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-fs

I am not able to access files from a hidden folder `/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses` in react-native-fs. Whenever I access I get back an empty array. I have granted `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission (Android). My code goes like this :

```js
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs'
RNFS.readDir(`${RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath}/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses`).then(res => {
    console.log(res)
})
```

I am able to access files of other folder but not anything that starts from '.'
How to access files of a hidden folder in react-native-fs ?

**Update:

This issue is in Android 11. Probably Android 10 as well.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem resolved for me by adding following permission in **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Worked for me too.
Visit to learn more https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files#all-files-access

Comment: In React native how can I use it since in react native there is no permission available? it is giving null permission to refer to the doc.  https://reactnative.dev/docs/permissionsandroid